# How to transform view only left, right, and top using CGAffineTransform?

Tags: ios, swift

Using `CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 2, y: 2)` will scale up the whole view.  Is there any way to transform the view only at the left, right, and top? Like the image below:

[image]

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly we’re looking at in this image? It’s not clear what the issue with it is, or how you would like it to be instead

Comment: I want to transform the only the view height

Comment: What’s “the view”? I see one black line (technically, rectangle) beside two shorter grey ones. Is all of it the view? One of them? No clue.

Comment: in the picture, there are 3 views. I want to transform the first view's height.

Comment: so can't u update the height constraint of that view?

Comment: is there any way to use transform ?

Comment: Maybe you're looking for [resizable images with cap insets](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/media/how-to-make-resizable-images-using-resizableimagewithcapinsets)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adjust your `anchorPoint` to `CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1)` with this your view will be scaled while maintain his y bottom position

```
customView?.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1)
UIView.animate(withDuration: 5, animations: { [customView] in
      customView?.layer.setAffineTransform(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 5, y: 5))
})
```

[image]